# Asserting two lists are equal in JUnit4

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit4

I've just begun writing unit tests using JUnit4. In the actual unit test method itself, I've created the 'expected' variable, and am trying to compare it with my code.

I'm comparing the ArrayLists using the Assert.assertEquals method in JUnit4, but there seems to be a whitespace at the end of the expected?

```
Expected: "java.util.ArrayList<[data]> "
Actual:   "java.util.ArrayList<[data]>"
```

Any explanations or help would be greatly appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: I'm also using JUnit4, but I get the expected error: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[a, b]> but was:<[a, bd]> at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88) for a list of String. I think you need to provide more code, so we (eg) see your "data" class.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the code you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  [`CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(list1, list2);`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEqualCollection-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-)

Or

You can also use

`Assert.assertArrayEquals(list1.toArray(new Integer[list1.size()]),
                          list2.toArray(new Integer[list2.size()]));`

For above example, I have assumed that type of list will be Integer but it will work for any data type.

Let me know if you still face any problems.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that lists of different class produce the same output. You may use the `list.toString().trim()` method to cut off the space(s), but that would only be a workaround.

Better use `list1.equals(list2`) or `Arrays.equals(array1,array2)`.